# Transparent text in beamer overlay

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

I have a large paragraph of text where I'd like on of the words to become bold and the rest semi-transparent. Getting one word bold is easy with `\textbf<2>{word}` but getting the rest semi-transparrent is tricky.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8x - danske bogstaver
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Problemformulering}
%
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\footnotesize
{
Vi vil lave en organisk syntese, hvor produktet er det aktive aromastof i vanilje, vanillin. Vores mål for produktet er, at det vil have den karakteristiske duft af vanilje og smagen deraf.
\\[\baselineskip]
Udgangspunktet for vores syntese er eugenol. Dette stof isomeriseres ved hjælp af en basekatalysator til isoeugenol, derefter PTC-oxideres det til vanillin, hvorefter stoffet også isoleres og oprenses. Vi har taget udgangspunkt i to forskellige synteseveje af Gery M. Lampman, som vi har kombineret, fordi oxidationen af eugenol i den ene syntese indeholdt kræftfremkaldende stoffer. Vi forventer et udbytte på \SI{20}{\percent} til \SI{30}{\percent}.
\\[\baselineskip]
Til at teste vores produkts renhed og beregning af udbyttet laver vi en række analyser. Her i blandt TLC, IR, \textbf<2>{NMR}, smeltpunkt- og kogepunktsbestemmelse og bestemmelse af indholdet af vanillin i vores produkt. Resultaterne vil vi se i forhold til, hvilke optimeringer som vi har lavet undervejs i syntesen. Vi vurderer også vores resultater i forhold til pris, kvalitet, tid og sikkerhed – herunder miljøforhold.
}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'd like all the text (except for the frametitle and the bolded word (NMR in this case) to become semi-transparrent like the way beamer does it with `\setbeamercovered`

[image: what the MWE gives]

Comment: This is probably not the most elegant solution, but how about `\uncover<1>{<stuff before NMR>} \textbf<2>{NMR} \uncover<1>{<stuff after NMR>}`?

Comment: @Argo I am not sure what you are asking, but does `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` in the preamble and `\pause` inside the document help?

Comment: Seems to work. I can't believe I didn't think of this before. Now, what value should I pass to ``\setbeamercovered{transparent=}`` for it to have same transparency as beamer does as default?

Comment: @Argo: Just use `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`

Comment: @Argo For your last question: I guess it is 15 (just checked, I am correct).

Comment: @KevinC thanks, this works. Do you mind making an answer so I can mark it as solved?

The value for ``\setbeamercovered{transparent=}`` is 25 after some testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but you can use

```
\uncover<1>{<stuff before NMR>} \textbf<2>{NMR} \uncover<1>{<stuff after NMR>}
```

## Code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8x - danske bogstaver
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Problemformulering}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\footnotesize
\uncover<1>{
Vi vil lave en organisk syntese, hvor produktet er det aktive aromastof i vanilje, vanillin. Vores mål for produktet er, at det vil have den karakteristiske duft af vanilje og smagen deraf.
\\[\baselineskip]
Udgangspunktet for vores syntese er eugenol. Dette stof isomeriseres ved hjælp af en basekatalysator til isoeugenol, derefter PTC-oxideres det til vanillin, hvorefter stoffet også isoleres og oprenses. Vi har taget udgangspunkt i to forskellige synteseveje af Gery M. Lampman, som vi har kombineret, fordi oxidationen af eugenol i den ene syntese indeholdt kræftfremkaldende stoffer. Vi forventer et udbytte på \SI{20}{\percent} til \SI{30}{\percent}.
\\[\baselineskip]
Til at teste vores produkts renhed og beregning af udbyttet laver vi en række analyser. Her i blandt TLC, IR, 
} %
\textbf<2>{NMR}%
\uncover<1>{, smeltpunkt- og kogepunktsbestemmelse og bestemmelse af indholdet af vanillin i vores produkt. Resultaterne vil vi se i forhold til, hvilke optimeringer som vi har lavet undervejs i syntesen. Vi vurderer også vores resultater i forhold til pris, kvalitet, tid og sikkerhed – herunder miljøforhold.}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```